# Core data | automatically generated String and Date attributes are optional even when not marked in swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject, optional-parameters

I have noticed the date and string attributes are always created as optionals in swift in auto-generated classes even when optional attribute is not selected.

In the [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/LifeofaManagedObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH16-SW1) also, all Date and string are shown as optional in example

> In Swift, you declare the properties using the @NSManaged keyword:
>
> class MyManagedObject: NSManagedObject {
>
> ```
> @NSManaged var title: String?
>
> @NSManaged var date: NSDate?
> ```
>
> }

Currently using swift 3.2 I dont want certain string attributes to be non- optional. What is the best way to make it as mandatory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two options

- Edit the `MyManagedObject` to make them non-optional. This means you need to maintain this class yourself and do any changes both in the core data model and the class
- Create a protocol (or sub class) with same attributes (you need to give them new names) but non-optional and implement this protocol in a separate extension to get and set original attributes and then use this protocol rather than `MyManagedObject` in your code.

If your data model is stable and won't be changed that much the first option is probably best.

Comment: I have tried the first option and it works but is it the right away as we have to maintain those files ourselves

Comment: @megha, I guess that is a question only you can answer

Answer (score -1):

> When the entities will be fetched from core data, some of the
>   properties of that entity may not have any value associated with them
>   and they will be nil. That is why it make sense to have the core data
>   properties as an optional.

Similarly, for an example, if you try to fetch the value of any key from a Dictionary in Swift, the value is always an optional as we may or may not have that key in the Dictionary. So, every time any property could be nil, make it optional.

Comment: A dictionary is not a good example. If you declare an attribute as non-optional in Core Data the compiler or the Core Data framework will complain at compile time if you forget to assign a value. So it's guaranteed that there is always a value. It's like registering default values in `UserDefaults`.  Personally I declare Core Data attributes non-optional as much as possible.

Comment: How do u make them non- optional?

Comment: @megha I mark them in the model as non-optional, select `Codegen : Manual/None` in the entitiy, create the classes with Menu `Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass` and remove the question marks.

Comment: Totally unrelated